# How does the splice function work here?

Tags: javascript, splice

Please help me out to understand this example.

```
function fun(a){
    this.length = 1;
    this.splice = [].splice;
    this[0] = a;
    return this;
};
```

Now, when I execute this function the result is an array.

```
f = new fun('hi');// result will be : ["hi"]
```

Why is that?

If I remove `this.length=1` OR `this.splice = [].splice`, the result will be different.

```
f = new fun('hi'); // result will be : fun {0: "a", splice: function}
```

Why is that?

I also see this technique used in jQuery. Please describe to me how this is working programmatically.

Comment: `splice` isn't even being used here, except that `this.splice` is referring to `Array.prototype.splice` (but in a way which creates an empty array to do so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing programmatical about it. It's just the way a browser/js engine chooses to show you some variable in the console.

The console is generally for developers as they are the ones who open those things. So the browser does a little sniffing to show the developer what this object he's/she's dealing with is. If it looks like an array, it probably should be printed like an array.

Like the following list shows, there are some differences between the browsers. Namely, IE and node do nothing. My interpretation is that printing in node should yield the complete view and not just the sniffed view. The `length` seems to satisfy Opera 12 to show it as an array.

Why browsers use `index`, `length` and `splice` is an entirely different story. It's probably the smallest set of properties that denote an array with high probability. Look at it, what else would it be, if not an array?

Chrome 36, Firefox 30 and Opera 18 behave the same way:

- `fun` as-is is `["hi"]`
- `fun` without `length` is *`fun { 0: 'hi', splice: function}`*
- `fun` without `splice` is *`fun { 0: 'hi', length: 1}`*

Opera 12 shows:

- `fun` as-is is `Object ["hi"]`
- `fun` without `length` is `Object`
- `fun` without `splice` is `Object ["hi"]`

IE 9 and node v0.8 did no sniffing at all (here IE output, node output very similar):

- `fun` as-is is `{0 : "hi", length : 1, splice : function splice() { [native code] }}`
- `fun` without `length` is `{0 : "hi", splice : function splice() { [native code] }}`
- `fun` without `splice` is `{0 : "hi", length : 1}`

Comment: O! this is what.. Its just way to representation ... great thanX bro to get me out from this browser's trouble... Ha Ha :)

Answer (score 2):

What you construct is not an array. I believe that your object may have a few features that let console recognize whether a given object is an array or not.

```
var arr = [];
var f = new fun('asd');

typeof arr; // "object"
typeof f; // "object"

arr instanceof Array; // "true"
f instanceof Array; // "false"
```

Comment: Ya! that is I want to know about that few features :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, how you can get that only "hi" result, because when I tried below code in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex59u/1/), I get `Object { 0: "hi", length: 1, splice: splice() }`. Which is make sense because what it does is creating an object which has 3 attributes(length, splice, and index[0]).

```
function fun(a){
this.length = 1; 
this.splice = [].splice;
this[0] = 'hi';
    return this;
}
f = new fun('hi');
console.log(f); //get the object f
console.log(f[0]); //get the string inside index-0
console.log(f.length); //get the length value which is already assigned before
console.log(f.splice); //it returns a function, which I believe a splice function
```

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your test. In my case the console outputs `["hi", splice:function]` which is an Array. If I remove the `splice` or the `length` part it outputs `fun { 0: "hi", ... }` which is an Object. I think this is the point.

Comment: Please check out my fiddle above, I would appreciate it if you can point out the wrong part.. I believe its the same code..

Comment: Yes, it's the same code. But actually I get `["hi", splice: function]` though (an Array) until I remove splice or length.

Comment: ThanX for reply... Ok if you run this function within console only then you will get better what I want to talk here... actually it is same ...