# (show-hidden class) jQuery click

Tags: jquery

I have n `<button>` class `.a` and n `<div>` class `.b`, with n undefined.
What is required is when I click on a class `.a` (1; 2; 3; ..;), then class `.b` (1; 2; 3; ..;) will be hidden.

Comment: Please share your code, otherwise your question is not answerable here.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking - could be as simple as `$(".a").click(function() { $(".a,.b").hide(); });`  If you only want *upto* **n** hidden, you could use `splice` eg `$(".a").splice(0, n).hide();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979528/splice-jquery-array-of-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).on("click",".a",function(e){

  var index=0;
  for(i=0;i<$(".a").length;i++){
    if( e.target == $(".a").eq(i)[0] ){
      index=i;
    }
  }

  $(document).find(".b").eq(index).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="a">A1</button><br>
<div class="b">B1</div>
<button class="a">A2</button><br>
<div class="b">B2</div>
<button class="a">A3</button><br>
<div class="b">B3</div>
<button class="a">A4</button><br>
<div class="b">B4</div>
<button class="a">A5</button><br>
<div class="b">B5</div>
```